# Where can one find implied OIS and Libor interest rates in Bloomberg?

Tags: interest-rates, bloomberg

I am struggling to find future interest rates for various tenors:

****EUR:**

- **Eonia OIS rates:** O/N (fixing), 1W, (2W), 1M, 3M, 6M, (9M), 12M
- **Euribor rates**: 1W, (2W), 1M, 3M, 6M, (9M), 12M, 18M, 2Y

NOTE: from 1 oct 20 EONIA will switch into ESTER

**GBP:**

- SONIA OIS
- GBP LIBOR.

**USD:**

- FED FUNDS OIS
- USD LIBOR.

**JPY:**

- TONA OIS
- JPY LIBOR

Rates should be **interpolated/extrapolated**

if you happen to be familiar with these rates provide me with tickers if it's possible because i have found only historical data in bloomberg

Comment: Would check this with the helpdesk.

Answer (score 1):

I believe `FWCM <GO>` will give you what you want (Forward Curve Matrix).
You can select a curve and then get the forwards by Tenor and Start Date.

Or use the BCurveStrip and BCurveFwd in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

Look on the BTMM page for the respective countries (the country can be changed with the dropdown menu).  Hover your mouse over the rate for which you are interested and a window will pop up with the ticker.

Answer (score 1):

`WCV` is a helpful starting point for rates / FX / vols.

For "interpolated/extrapolated" rates (not necessary for all tenors), you can try `CRVF` (curve finder) and then pick currency and appropriate curve.